# C# Unity How to attach ParticleSystem to gameobject with script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to attach particle system to a player when it get an item

Hi!

I have this file where i use to launch FX and Sounf FX when players get an item. I attach this file to each player and for each i choose effect and sound. But i don't see the effect in game :

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LaunchFxForItem : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioSource audioSource;
    [Header("Fx Position for Health")]
    public GameObject fxForHealth;
    public AudioClip sfxForHealth;
    public float xFxForHealth; 
    public float yFxForHealth;
    public float wFxForHealth;
    [Header("Fx Position for TotalHealth")]
    public GameObject fxForTotalHealth;
    public AudioClip sfxForTotalHealth;
    public float xFxForTotalHealth; 
    public float yFxForTotalHealth;
    public float wFxForTotalHealth;
    [Header("Fx Position for Spraypaint")]
    public GameObject fxForSpraypaint;
    public AudioClip sfxForSpraypaint;
    public float xFxForSpraypaint; 
    public float yFxForSpraypaint;
    public float wFxForSpraypaint;

    //**********************//
    //***** LifeCycleI *****//
    //**********************//

    private void Awake() {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    //**************************//
    //***** Visual effects *****//
    //**************************//

    public void LaunchVisualFx(PlayerInGame player, GameObject source) { print("LaunchVisualFx");
        ParticleSystem ps = source.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>(); print("PS : " + ps);
        ps.Play();
    } // LaunchVisualFx

    //*************************//
    //***** Sound effects *****//
    //*************************//

    public void LaunchSoundFx(AudioClip source) {
        audioSource.clip = source;
        audioSource.volume = 2f;
        audioSource.Play();
    } // LaunchSoundFx
}
```

i call it on another file, when one player get an item. Like that :

```cs
player.GetComponent<LaunchFxForItem>().LaunchVisualFx(player, player.GetComponent<LaunchFxForItem>().fxForTotalHealth);
                player.GetComponent<LaunchFxForItem>().LaunchSoundFx(player.GetComponent<LaunchFxForItem>().sfxForTotalHealth);
                this.GetComponent<Health>().RestoreTotalLife(player);
```

Sound effect is played, but i don't see the Particle on the player. Do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: well you might need to move the particle system to the player if its not already on it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what the particle is or what it is used for, but you usually dont want to add a particle system component on a player. I advise you to make a prefab with the particle system component (make sure play on awake is true), save the prefab in your assets, and instantiate the prefab in the function instead. To save memory, you might also want to consider implementing  a system where the gameobject is destroyed after some time (again, not sure what your particle is so I don't know if this will be applicable to you). If you want the particle to follow your player, instead of making a prefab, you can also just make an empty game object, attach your particle system component to it, (play on awake false) and call it in your function as you like.

If you need help with any of this, feel free to comment on this answer, and I will gladly help you through it.

Happy game developing!